# How do I install vue/cli in ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

I have tried using `npm install -g @vue/cli` to install vue/cli in ubuntu 18.04. But it keeps giving me an error.

[image: the error I'm seeing]

Comment: Please read your error message and take special note of the third line from the end. Also in the future rather post the text itself instead of a screenshot.

Comment: I am new to ubuntu, and new to stack as well. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: welcome to ask Ubuntu. Please don't post screen shots of the terminal or of code, instead  post it as a code snippet or a block of code, see [accepted-formatting-guidelines](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15446/lets-agree-on-some-commonly-accepted-formatting-guidelines)

Comment: Thank you!!! I will post as formatting guidelines after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to install a `npm` package globally and `npm` stores this packages inside `/usr/local/lib` folders. Your `user` does not have permission to edit files outside of the `home` directory for security reason.

**Option 1** - Stop using `npm` and start using `yarn`

The issue is connected to `npm` so I would stop using it and [install `yarn` as in their official guide](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#debian-stable). Packages should be stored inside your `home` directory, even when installed globally [like the other package manager do (`Yarn`, `rbenv` etc..)](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2049), for this and many other reasons I would stop using `npm`.

**Option 2** - Try to fix npm

There are [several solution proposed in this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules-react), none of which really good options.

The best option is changing the permission to the folder `/usr/local/lib` [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51024493/7295772)

```
sudo chown -R [owner]:[owner] /usr/local/lib
```

Then follow the [official `@vue/cli` installation instructions for either `npm` or `yarn`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html)

**Options 3** - Install it via apt package manager

I don't suggest you to use apt package manager, as you may work with different projects which use different versions of this package. If **project 1** uses `@vue/cli` **version 1**, then you update because you want to work on **project 2**, **project 1** may not work anymore.

```
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli`, and then enter your password.  This is the preferred method over actually using the root/Administrator user.

Comment: You are actually using the root user with `sudo ..`. This is not a good way to install it because it will polute your `usr/..` folder. It belongs to `home/user` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You find the solution in the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally):

> Reinstall npm with a node version manager (recommended)

To reinstall, you don't need to remove current version of npm.

Just install nvm (node version manager) like this:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.2/install.sh | bash
```

and then install latest stable version with

```
npm install stable
```

Now you may install `vue/cli` globally without permission issues:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking for various answers on the internet, I just spent an hour tearing my hair out over this issue. I managed to resolve this problem with Adams solution looking into [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally).

What I learned is that instead of looking for a problem all over the internet for (mostly deprecated) solutions, I should first take a close look at exactly what errors does my terminal show up and start from there.

This was my solution for using Vue CLI on Ubuntu 18.04. Thank you.

Comment: It would be good, to write the steps you have done. Hyperlinks can some day be dead.

Comment: I am sorry, you're absolutely right. My answer should be more technical and also easy to follow for others. I can't really tell what was the whole process I took since I was just copy-pasting messages my terminal was printing to me. I will paste steps from original answer that finally had me resolve my problem:

(1) If you don't have (I already had), install nvm:
"curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.2/install.sh | bash",
(2) Install stable version "nvm install stable", (3) Install vue/cli globally without permission issues "npm install -g @vue/cli".

Comment: Also, I tried using yarn instead of npm like said before, along with many other solutions proposed on various forums and sites. Nothing like this solved my problem. I came across some invalid (deprecated) node versions errors, and I think at last that was the main reason why this particular solution helped me in the end. Like I said, I have been going through copy-paste mantra all the time and once again: I recommend newbies to take more technical approach to your problems, or you can end up not knowing how you managed to help yourself, and struggle again once you end up in similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

nodejs manager as mentioned above (Adam) is the key, years of knowledge now is the winning recommendation in this ALWAYS out-of-date node-js "ecosystem"
please consider this manager: NVS: https://github.com/jasongin/nvs

pros:

- very clean install (non-dirtify-your-system)
- no root (forget sudo)
- change anytime your working version (lts, latest,...)
- multi-platform, works for win10 (msys2 no-issues)
- eat-your-own-dog-food: it is made in JS

cons:

- only for development
- you need to use git (for a newbie)

Steps ([github link](https://github.com/jasongin/nvs)):

1. export NVS_HOME="$HOME/.nvs"
2. git clone https://github.com/jasongin/nvs "$NVS_HOME"
3. **. "$NVS_HOME/nvs.sh" install**
4. nvs   # choose your node version

then finally:
5) npm install -g @vue/cli